# How to remove complet order notification for specyfic product id in woocommerce?

Tags: php, wordpress, email, notifications, woocommerce

How to remove complet order notification for specyfic product id in woocommerce?

I no how to disable this notification of all products

```
  remove_action('woocommerce_order_status_completed_notification', array($wc_emails->emails['WC_Email_Customer_Completed_Order'], 'trigger'));
```

But can I do this only for one product id?

Answer (score 0):

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_email_recipient_completed_order', 'detener_envio_admin_inscripciones', 10, 2 );
add_filter( 'woocommerce_email_recipient_new_order', 'detener_envio_admin_inscripciones', 10, 2 );

function detener_envio_admin_inscripciones( $recipient, $order  ) {
    if ( ! is_a( $order, 'WC_Order' ) ) return $recipient;
    
    if(!empty(get_post_meta($order,'XXXXXXX',true))){
        return;
    }
    return $recipient;
}
```

You would have to put a foreach as a condition to see if the product you want is in that order.